# In a kubernetes scenario, when software says it benefits from lots of disk space for filesystem cache, are they referring to PVCs?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, kubernetes, solr, filesystems

Applications like MongoDB & ElasticSearch & SOLR all say that they benefit from having free disk space because they rely on the filesystem cache.

In a kubernetes infrastructure, does that mean that bigger PVCs benefit them? Or does that mean bigger "ephemeral storage" on the node benefit them?

Links:

MongoDB: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/storage/#to-what-size-should-i-set-the-wiredtiger-internal-cache-

SOLR: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SOLR/SolrPerformanceProblems#SolrPerformanceProblems-OSDiskCache

Elasticsearch: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/preload-data-to-file-system-cache.html

Thank you!

Comment: Disk cache refers to _memory_ that is available and used, so that the underlying file system doesn't have to be considered at all. Ephemeral or persistent storage shouldn't matter in regard to that as far as I know.

Comment: So really, it just means try to have more RAM... Any chance you've got a reference for this? Happy to accept it as the answer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache

Comment: oh. what I meant was that if you were to give me that as an answer with that link, I'll accept the answer :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disk cache refers to memory that is available and used, so that the underlying file system doesn't have to be considered at all. Ephemeral or persistent storage shouldn't matter in regard to that as far as I know.

[The page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) makes sure that currently unused memory is used to keep frequently accessed parts of the file system in memory. Since the memory isn't required by any other processes, it's instead used to speed up what's usually the slowest memory - the actual disk. If the whole database / index can be kept in memory instead of having to be read from disk when a query is to be resolved, the performance of most/all databases will greatly increase.